# How to import a simple XML file using ssis...A component does not have any inputs or outputs

Tags: ssis

I have a very simple XML file and I want to import the file using SSIS.

Control flow - I have a data flow on it

Data flow - I have data flow source as xml source. On edit I provoided the XML location and generated the XSD. When I see the columns tab I dont see any columns available.

Here is the sample XMl file

```
<book>
    <title>Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Master Data Services</title>
    <category>Information Technology</category>
    <author>Jeremy Kashel</author>
    <review>excellent book</review>
</book>
```

I see this message 'A component does not have any inputs or outputs'. Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What would you expect the data flow's metadata to look like? Have 4 fields in it: title, category, book, and author or 1 field: book which carries along the 4 properties?

Comment: 1 field book which carries all the other properties.